# How to extract all the dependencies from the pom.xml?

Tags: java, apache, maven, dependencies, pom.xml

I’m trying to extract the dependency of maven projects to make some analysis on the dependencies. As of right the idea is to extract the dependencies from the pom.xml by parsing all the `pom.xml` files of a projects of interest and writing an algorithm to cluster them back together. To extract all the properties I plan to use the the [pomparser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pom-parser). Once I have it in JSON format I write a algorithm to extract all the information.

I was wondering if you have any other / better suggestions on how to extract the dependencies from a pom? I have seen some a posts about MavenXpp3Reader, but have not understood the benefits of using it. If you have a better strategy or any input, please let me know :)

Comment: Use a Maven command as in the answer of StuPointerException. Parsing the XML (or the equivalent JSON) is a nightmare because you would need to go through all the Maven properties, environment variables and so on.

Answer (score 4):

I've found this command to be very useful:

```
mvn dependency:tree -DoutputType=tgf -DappendOutput=true -DoutputFile=output.tgf
```

This will output the dependency tree in [Trivial Graph Format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trivial_Graph_Format) (which is very easy to parse) into a file called `output.tgf`.  This has the benefit of being able to identify transitive dependencies, if required.